# Few of the accounts in active directory are missing distribution lists and security groups

Tags: active-directory

I face issue with the AD. At some point I can see that the NTID is part of certain group. And later the group is missing for that account. 
What could be the cause for this issue and how to fix the problem.

This happens in the Identity management system.